# PyQt5 でPrivateBrowsingを有効化したい

Tags: python, python3, pyqt5, pyqt, browser

私は現在、PyQt5を用いて自作のブラウザを作成しています。
その過程で何個か(例えばPrivateBrowsingなど)のQWebSettingsを使用する必要性が出てきました。
そして、私はインターネットで調べた結果を何個か試してみましたがそれはどれもうまくいきませんでした。

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings

self.webEngineView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)
            self.webEngineView.page().settings().WebAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
```

が私が最後に試したコードです。ですがこのコードはQWebSettingsが存在しないと言われエラーが出てしまいました。

私は一通り、考えてみましたがどれもうまくいきませんでした

どうしたら私はQWebSettingsを使うことが出来ますか？

Comment: インストールしたPyQt5のバージョンはいくつでしょうか? Webページ( https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtwebengine/ )の記載を見ると、5.12以降は別パッケージになっているようですので)

Comment: 5.15でした..
別パッケージと言うと上記のコードと同じことをやろうとした場合
どのような工程を行えば良いのでしょうか？
プログラム初心者でして..右も左もわからず困っています

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5の5.15であれば、`PyQtWebEngine`パッケージをインストールするのはいかがでしょうか?
(コマンドラインは以下の通り)

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

参考: https://pypi.org/project/PyQtWebEngine/